# selenium webdriver TypeError: to_capabilities() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this specific error :

> desired_capabilities = options.to_capabilities() TypeError:
>    to_capabilities() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

I don't understand what is wrong because Options has parenthesis.

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.parse
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options



width = 400
height = 768
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--lang=en')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
chrome_options.add_argument('--mute-audio')
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument('--force-device-scale-factor=1')
chrome_options.add_argument(f'window-size={width}x{height}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=Options)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized an instance of `Options()` Class by the name **`chrome_options`**.

So you have to pass **`chrome_options`** as an argument while spinning up the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome). So you have to change the line as:

```
webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Effectively, your line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Sometimes the answer is in front of us.... Sorry, I have to wait 8 min to validate your asnwer. Thank you for your help :)